# Laravel scss npm run dev - Can't resolve '../images/bg-main.png'

Tags: css, laravel, npm, sass

I have Laravel project and I want to generate css file from scss. My `webpack.mix.js` file looks like this:

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/style.scss', 'public/css/style.css');
```

when I run command npm run dev I have error:

```
ERROR in ./resources/assets/sass/style.scss
Module build failed: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../images/bg-main.png' in '/var/www/html/bitpay/resources/assets/sass'

ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--4-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--4-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--4-5!./resources/assets/sass/style.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../images/bg-main.png' in '/var/www/html/bitpay/resources/assets/sass'
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--4-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--4-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--4-5!./resources/assets/sass/style.scss 7:14663-14695
 @ ./resources/assets/sass/style.scss
 @ multi ./node_modules/laravel-mix/src/builder/mock-entry.js ./resources/assets/sass/style.scss

ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--4-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--4-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--4-5!./resources/assets/sass/style.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../images/bg-recommendations.png' in '/var/www/html/bitpay/resources/assets/sass'
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--4-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--4-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--4-5!./resources/assets/sass/style.scss 7:17599-17642 7:22181-22224
 @ ./resources/assets/sass/style.scss
 @ multi ./node_modules/laravel-mix/src/builder/mock-entry.js ./resources/assets/sass/style.scss
```

How to add images folder to compilation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `mix` cannot find the image `bg-main.png` that you are referring to inside `style.scss`.

You can either add the mix option not to process css urls as shown here:

```js
mix.options({
    processCssUrls: false
});
```

That has some consequences:

- mix will not check for the image's existence.
- mix will not automatically copy the image to the public directory.

The better solution is to place the image where mix expects it: mix expects `../images/bg-main.png` to be inside directory `resources/images/`

References:

- https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/url-rewriting
- https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/faq#why-is-it-saying-that-an-image-in-my-css-file-cant-be-found-in-node_modules

Answer (score 1):

That image files maybe not exist.

Comment: It exists in folder: var/www/html/myproject/public/images/bg-main.png

Comment: I've moved folder with images to the sass folder

Answer (score 1):

It is an incorrect path error, you used `./images/bg-main.png` somewhere in your CSS. So locate that instance and change the path thus `background-image:url('~/images/bg-main.png');`